# Defining variables after calling functions gives me a compilation error

Tags: c, turbo-c

This works

```
main()
{
   int c;
   struct books Book1;
   c = getchar( );
   return 0;
}
```

This doesn't

```
main()
{
   int c;
   c = getchar( );
   struct books Book1;
   return 0;
}
```

> Expression syntax in function main (and points to the space after the word 'struct')

This doesn't either because the definition of B is below `c = getchar();`, error points to the space between "int" and "b"

```
main()
{
   int c;
   struct books Book1;
   c = getchar( );
   int b;
   return 0;
}
```

Is the problem that i have to define every variable before calling functions, or is it something else?

Is this how C works, or is it a turbo C thing?

**Edit:** found duplicates after realizing that i meant to say "definition" not "declaration"

- [Where you can and cannot declare new variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474100/where-you-can-and-cannot-declare-new-variables-in-c)
- [Can't define variables after a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058143/cant-define-variables-after-a-function-call)

Comment: Because Turbo C is an obsolete compiler from a time when declaring variables after you've called code was illegal.

Comment: Turbo C is not a C compiler, because C is first standardize in 1989, long after Turbo C was released. As a result it contains a lot of non-standard things http://stackoverflow.com/q/3920351/995714 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1961828/995714

Comment: alright thank you, i found a couple of duplicates after looking up "defining variable before function call" instead of "declaring variable after function call", [Where you can and cannot declare new variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058143/cant-define-variables-after-a-function-call) and [Can't define variables after a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058143/cant-define-variables-after-a-function-call) , should i delete the question?

Comment: You *should* use an up-to-date compiler, unless you don't want the benefits of technology improvements from the last thirty years such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [dramatically](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)... [improved](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html)... [optimisations](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#profile-guided-optimization)...

Comment: Of course the use of such old technology is for no practical purpose, in my case it's just an assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C89, variables must be declared in the beginning of a block. The restriction was removed since C99.

It's not a surprise that Turbo C, an outdated compiler, doesn't support this C99 feature.